# Only csv file can import from GCS to Dataflow and BigQuery using Cloud Composer - Apache Airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a usecase: There are several files type in GCS like json, csv, txt,.. but I only want to choose **csv file**, use Dataflow in Python to transform them (such as rename fields,...), then write it to BigQuery. And the main requirement is use **Airflow sensors without Cloud Fucntion** to trigger them whenever a new csv file import to GCS.

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.gcs import GCSObjectExistenceSensor

from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataflowTemplateOperator

PROJECT = 'abc'
ZONE = 'us-central1-c'
BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket_testing'
BQ_DATASET = "abc.dataset_name"
LOCATION = "US"

DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'gcs to bigquery using dataflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'schedule_interval': '@daily',
    'dataflow_default_options': {
               'project': PROJECT,
               'zone': ZONE,
               'stagingLocation': BUCKET_NAME
           }
}

ENVIRONMENT = {
    "bypassTempDirValidation": "false",
    "maxWorkers": "20",
    "numWorkers": "1",
    "serviceAccountEmail": "abc8932097-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "tempLocation": "gs://composer_bucket",
    "ipConfiguration": "WORKER_IP_UNSPECIFIED",
    "additionalExperiments": [
    "sideinput_io_metrics"
    ]
}

PARAMETERS = {
    "outputTable": "abc:dataset_name.how_to_define_here", // how to got multiple table from multiple csv
    "bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory": "gs://composer_bucket",
 }



with DAG('dag_sensor', default_args=DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS,dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=3),schedule_interval='00 * * * *') as dag:
        gcs_file_exists = GCSObjectExistenceSensor(
            task_id="gcs_object_sensor",
            bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
            object='*.csv',
            mode='poke',
        )

        my_dataflow_job = DataflowTemplateOperator(
            task_id='transfer_from_gcs_to_bigquery',
            template='???', //what I need to write here
            parameters=PARAMETERS,
            environment=ENVIRONMENT,
            dag=dag
        )


        my_bq_result = BigQueryOperator(
            task_id='write_to_bq',
            use_legacy_sql=False,
            write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
            dag = dag
        )

gcs_file_exists >> my_dataflow_job >> my_bq_result
```

I am a newbie here, so please point me a detailed example.

Many thanks!

Comment: Which version of Airflow and Apache Beam are you using ?

Comment: hi @DevYns, I'm using Airflow 2.4.0, apache-beam-2.41.0 and Python 3.9.7

Comment: Hi @NhuDao, For your requirement, you can use Pub/Sub to send message whenever a new file is uploaded into the Cloud Storage and then you can use  FileSystems to match the file pattern as mentioned in this [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/file-processing/). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: because our requirement is want to use Airflow sensor to detect a new CSV file is uploaded to GCS, and the pipeline flow is: GCS -> Dataflow (just to transform data)-> BigQuery to orchestrate job. So here, we don't be allowed to use Pub/sub :(

Comment: Hi @NhuDao, For your requirement, I would suggest you to use [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf) since it is the easiest way to trigger an event whenever a new file is uploaded in GCS. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, yes I know we can you Cloud Functions but I was required to use Airflow sensor to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi @NhuDao, for your requirement, you can try using [GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/gcs/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.gcs.GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor) in which you can  check for the type of the file. For source code, you can refer this [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/gcs.html#GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor).

Comment: I used GCSObjectExistenceSensor, it's work. But I wonder if I have multiple csv files to load them in Bigquery, is it the same way ?